# Manually increment int field to EF database in MVC C#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have an MVC application that has some CRUD functionality, I've noticed that upon creating a new record, one of the fields that supposed to be automatically generated returns 0. Is there a way I can populate this field to increment every time a new record is created. Thanks.

**Test shows how StoreNumber remains 0 whenever I add records.**
[image]

**Controller:**

```
 public ActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewBag.CustomerID = new SelectList(db.Customers, "CustomerID", "CustomerCompanyName");
            return View();
        }



        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "StoreID,CustomerID,StoreName,StoreUID,StoreNumber,StoreLogo,StoreLogoPath,StoreAddress,StoreCity,StoreRegion,StoreCountry")] Store store)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                store.StoreUID = Guid.NewGuid();

                db.Stores.Add(store);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            ViewBag.CustomerID = new SelectList(db.Customers, "CustomerID", "CustomerCompanyName", store.CustomerID);
            return View(store);
        }
```

**Store Class**

```
public partial class Store
    {
        public int StoreID { get; set; }
        public int CustomerID { get; set; }
        public string StoreName { get; set; }

        public System.Guid StoreUID { get; set; }

        public int StoreNumber { get; set; }
        public string StoreLogo { get; set; }
        public string StoreLogoPath { get; set; }
        public string StoreAddress { get; set; }
        public string StoreCity { get; set; }
        public string StoreRegion { get; set; }
        public string StoreCountry { get; set; }

        public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public partial class Store
    {
        public int StoreID { get; set; }
        public int CustomerID { get; set; }
        public string StoreName { get; set; }

        public System.Guid StoreUID { get; set; }
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int StoreNumber { get; set; }
        public string StoreLogo { get; set; }
        public string StoreLogoPath { get; set; }
        public string StoreAddress { get; set; }
        public string StoreCity { get; set; }
        public string StoreRegion { get; set; }
        public string StoreCountry { get; set; }

        public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
    }
```

just use DatabaseGenerated attribute to your field

Comment: It is still returning 0

Comment: use this one 
 modelBuilder.Entity<Store>().Property(a => a.StoreNumber 
                          ).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

Comment: Yes I have management studio, where do I add that code? In the Store.cs?

Comment: public class SchoolContext: DbContext 
{
    public SchoolDBContext(): base() 
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Standard> Standards { get; set; }
        
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        //Configure default schema
        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("Admin");
    }
}

Comment: in your context class you have a method protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder){}

Comment: just add modelBuilder.Entity<Store>().Property(a => a.StoreNumber ).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identit‌​y); this

Comment: @GareginHambardzumyan I'm pretty sure `StoreID` is already the identity. `StoreNumber` is different.

Comment: If you want i can connect with you via team viever and see your code

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test1] (
    [Id]                 INT                   NOT NULL       IDENTITY (1, 1),
```

You need DB Table with autoincrement

Comment: I'm pretty sure `StoreID` is already the identity. `StoreNumber` is different.

Comment: I think only identity is auto incremented.

Answer (score 0):

Each table can only have one identity generated automatically.  I assume this is the StoreID field.  Thus, you'd have to mark StoreID with [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)].  Or if the column is actually Id (int) and already marked with [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)], then that means no other int fields are going to get auto updated by the built in identity features of SQL.  Thus, you have to manually set the number as there is nothing updating that for you.

Comment: Ah I understand, how can I manually set the number ? Thank you.